# While loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to python and am having problems seeing why this code does not work. I would like it to return [10,122,2].

```
close = [5000,5010,5132,5134]

def difference():
    x = 0
    data = []
    while x < len(close):
        diff = close[x+1]-close[x]
        data.append(diff)
        x = x + 1
    return data
```

it returns "IndexError: list index out of range" but my understanding was that the while loop only runs when the condition is met. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Think about what happens when x is 3

Answer (score 7):

You limit `x` to be smaller than `len(close)`, but the last index of a list is at `len(close) - 1` (0 based indexing). This means in the last iteration of your loop `x + 1` will be equal to `len(close)` and out of bounds.

This works:

```
while x < len(close) - 1:
    diff = close[x+1]-close[x]
    data.append(diff)
    x = x + 1
```

Your code can also be simplified to:

```
data = [elem - close[i - 1] for i, elem in enumerate(close) if i]
```

This list comprehension:

- Loops over all elements in `close`.
- Uses `enumerate()` to generate an index for each element, giving us both the index `i` and the element `elem`.
- Calculates the difference between the current element and the previous element in `close` (using the index - 1), *except* when the index is `0`, effectively skipping the one element for which there is no preceding element in `close`.

Demo:

```
>>> close = [5000,5010,5132,5134]
>>> [elem - close[i - 1] for i, elem in enumerate(close) if i]
[10, 122, 2]
```

Comment: `[elem - close[i - 1] for i, elem in enumerate(close) if i]` saves making the temporary slice

Comment: @gnibbler: nice one, I'll steal that then. :-)

Answer (score 2):

see this: `close[x+1]`

That's the problem.
Indeed x will always be a valid index according to the condition you wrote. But in the final iteration, you will find that `x+1` is not. If you want to avoid going out of range in this line, you will have to subtract 1 from the maximum value you are checking against.